# How can I send image to API which is already exists on server?

Tags: api, laravel-5, upload, media, guzzle

I need to send **image** to API **which is already uploaded to server**. How can I do that?

Application is developed on Laravel Framework 5.7. For API I'm using GuzzleHTTP Client package.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: What have you tried already?

Comment: If you know it is already stored you have some kind of id or other handle to find it again use that handle.

Comment: You need to send the image URL in your API response.

Comment: Actually I tried and implement it currently uploaded image and able to send it to API. But unfortunately don't know how to send it directly let's say from server folder to API

Answer (score 0):

You could try to encode your file to Base64, then send it back from your API.

Assume this is your image:

```
$image_path = storage_path($model->image);

$image_data = \File::get($image_path);
```

Returning Image Encoded on Base64:

```
return response()->json(['image' => base64_encode($image_data)]);
```

Others way to make your response (with the file):

1. https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/responses#json-responses
2. https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/responses#file-downloads